# SP13: Connecting Content Types

Tags: 2013, workflow, javascript, content-type, custom-list

Working in SharePoint 2013.  Have a custom list with a bunch on content types.  Some of the content types share the same columns.  My assumption was that if a column is filled in one column type it will also appear other column types that share the same column.  Wrong!  That didn't work.

Intent: I want to connect the column types based on the same columns. So, if I go to Content Type A and fill in information.  Then the same column information will appear in Content Type B (if they share the same columns).

Can this be done?

Comment: When you say "go to content type A and fill in information", which you then want to see in content type B, do you mean default values for particular columns?  Or do you mean the value of a particular column on a specific list item?

Comment: @DylanCristy Sorry for the confusion.  Yes I mean the value of a particular column for the specific list item.  Thank you for your response.

Comment: Then what Nate says is true.  Keep in mind that an item can only be one content type at a time.  So if you create a new list item that is Content Type A, and fill out information for it and *save* it, then later go back and edit it and change the content type to Content Type B, then any columns that are in both Content Type A and Content Type B will retain their value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the default behavior of content types in SharePoint.  If you have multiple content types setup on the same list and have the same fields attached to those content types, then filling in and **saving** the form within one content type will update the field in the list for that item.  Editing the item in any other content type with that field in it should show the value previously input.  Maybe you are filling in the field, changing the content type before saving? You'd have to save the form and then go back in to see the change reflected in the other content types.  Changing the content type in the edit form after updating the form will just remove your value.  Not sure if that's the issue, but thought i'd throw it out there.

Comment: Thank you, Nate!  So, you are saying that as long as the column types have the same columns the information entered will appear in the other content types?  If so, It is not working for me.  Do you have any idea what I have done incorrectly?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by 'column types'.  Do you mean content types?  If so, yes, if you place the same field in both content types, the value will always be the same in both content types (that is once the value has been saved).  Again, if you input the value and immediately change the content type it'll clear the value in both. Once the value is saved it should appear the same in any content type where that field appears.  I work with content types quite a bit and i've never seen an instance where a field value was different from one content type to the next.

Comment: They only thing i can think to check is maybe create a custom view of your data and see if the field name is listed twice or if there are two fields with similar names which might be throwing you off.  I generally create my own site content types but i wonder if it's possible to add a global content type which has a field with the same name.  I wouldn't think so, but maybe.

Comment: Thank you, Nate!  I am going to recreate the content types and try again.  Thank you for your help! This has been very helpful.  Maybe I need to locate information on how to create content types correctly.  I must of did something wrong somewhere. Thanks again!